# mysqli_prepare() Query working on localhost but not when uploaded online, variables on prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am currently making the login system of an item inventory list for a client's website.

I keep getting these errors online when testing the login form :

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/greyan/public_html/shoplogin/login.php on line 44
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/greyan/public_html/shoplogin/login.php on line 48

What troubles me is that this only happens when I upload it online in the web server but not when I am viewing the site through localhost.

```
//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
$str = trim($str);
global $conn;
return $conn->real_escape_string($str);
}


//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = '*Username missing';
$errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = '*Password missing';
$errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
$_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
session_write_close();
header("location: index.php");
exit();
}

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ") ;
$sql->bind_param("ss", $username, $password) ;

$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->get_result();
```

I am really confused as to why these errors keep happening. The number of variables in the prepared statement seems to be correct as stated on the bind_param() parameters.

Comment: Another confusion is that you are ESCAPING the data although you are using prepared statements. Escaping data for prepared statements is counter productive, you will change the data and see escape characters when reading data back from the db.

Comment: Your query doesn't actually use `?` placeholders, but interpolates the two variables instead. Which is what the error message is about.

Comment: Sorry I am currently new to mysqli and just followed previous examples of queries and just experimented on prepared statements for the security of the login. Many thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't escape your strings and replace the variable names '$username' and '$password' with question marks (?). Also, do not use the single quotes.

As a security precaution, I also recommend using the password_hash function as it seems you are likely storing your passwords as plain text.

Comment: Fixed my answer slightly.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently new to mysql and php and this really helped me get over my problem.

Comment: No need to ask for permission to ask, just ask. :)

Comment: Really appreciate the fast reply!

Well, another one of my problem is that my webserver uses PHP 5.3.29

According to my research, the password_hash function only works on (PHP 5 >= 5.5).

I discovered then an alternative which is the crypt function.
I also discovered that bcrypt is one of the most securest way of hashing  user input.


So my question is,

Is there any way to hash the current passwords inside my mysql database with bcrypt using phpmyadmin?

Comment: or any kind of hash that would make me able to compare to what crypt() does when hashing user input.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to a more recent PHP version? Or are you going through a webhost?

Comment: Unfortunately no because I am going through a webhost.

Anyway I found a solution whereas I manually hashed the passwords in the users table. with PASSWORD() in the query.

And I also put that inside the query where the password is being searched.

Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Yes, a better way, though a bit more to set up, would be using the password_compat library which gives older PHP versions access to the new functions: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: I see! Can that library be installed in any older versions of PHP, though it says on the site that it is not compatible with my hosts version(5.3.2) only on versions(5.3.7) and above. I have no chance of upgrading my php version because of my hosting. Thanks a lot for the really helpful information that you have given. I now know that you can install libraries in order to access newer php functions. :)

Comment: Earlier you said you had PHP version 5.3.29, which I think should be above 5.3.7. Or do you only have 5.3.2?

Comment: Also, from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html it says "PASSWORD() is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications."

Comment: I was guessing that PHP version 5.3.29 is just the same as 5.3.2 is it not? and is it above 5.3.7?

Also checked the link that you have given and how do you think should I approach my problem? 

I would prefer to install the password_compat library that you have mentioned but I do not know if it is compatible with my current version of php which is (5.3.29). But as you mentioned again it is above 5.3.7?

Comment: You can see the different PHP release dates for the versions here: http://php.net/releases/

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you so much, you have been a great help!